# Can I place a link on my profile description?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, profile-page, hyperlinks

I have a stack overflow account, and also I have an account in certain freelance jobs sites, is there a problem if I place a link there in case someone would like to hire me?

Or am I violating any terms?

Comment: When your title is "Can I do X?", and your question contains "Or is doing X bad?", it makes it difficult to reply with yes or no! I was surprised to see "Nope" as the answer to the title question

Comment: You can certainly put those links into your profile (but not in your posts). But if you want someone to hire you, you might also want to consider getting a profile at http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 6):

Nope, you are free to link to other sites from your profile, as long as it is not obvious spam (buy V1@gra here!).

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought the profile box was free-form. If you want to put spam links in there, why should we stop you?

Comment: Because the TOS specifically outlaw spam (as well as personal attacks and abusive language).

Answer (score 6):

Nope, that's perfectly fine. (as long as you're not spamming, of course.) Many people do it.

In fact, there's even a "website" field you can fill in if you want to post a link to your website!

Comment: Yeah I have my personal blog there, but I wanted to show my profile in the description :)

Comment: @RicardoE Alright, that is perfectly okay then. :)

Comment: Thanks man :) have a nice day.